# I'm trying to make a Music App with Python But I'm getting an error which I can't fix

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a music app using python for my 12th grade project but I'm getting an error which I have no idea how to fix. What I'm indenting to do is to make fully functional app-like python program with GUI and is able to play both online and offline music.

Initially I started with just a program in which we can search and find the first result which comes in Youtube and just play it, pause it and stop it. Which I later improved so that we can play upto the first 10 results in Youtube.I actually got the idea for the searching and finding part from stack overflow itself (which was very helpful btw.) and developed the rest of the code from it. We also can play/pause/stop the music too. But I wanted it to look even more good so...I added a GUI using tkinter which was pretty hard at first but soon it was easy enough. What I can do now is Type the music name in the Tkinter window and Search button (added the Search button so it will run the 'link-finding-and-playing-program' when I press it).
The libraries I use now are:

- requests.
- pafy
- python-vlc
- tkinter

CODE OF THE PROGRAM:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import re,requests, urllib.parse, urllib.request
    import vlc
    import pafy
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('475x225'); root.title('PyMu6')
    Entry = Entry(root, width=26,font=('Circular',13))
    Entry.place(x=127,y=17)
    def search():
        music_name = Entry.get()
        print(music_name)
        if type(music_name)==str:
            query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": music_name})
            formatUrl = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
            search_results = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", formatUrl.read().decode())
            clip = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[0]))
            clip1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[0])
            clip2 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[1])
            clip3 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[2])
            clip4 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[3])
            clip5= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[4])
            clip6 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[5])
            clip7 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[6])
            clip8 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[7])
            clip9 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[8])
            clip10 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "{}".format(search_results[9])
            title1 = pafy.new(clip1)
            title2 = pafy.new(clip2)
            title3 = pafy.new(clip3)
            title4 = pafy.new(clip4)
            title5 = pafy.new(clip5)
            title6 = pafy.new(clip6)
            title7 = pafy.new(clip7)
            title8 = pafy.new(clip8)
            title9 = pafy.new(clip9)
            title10 = pafy.new(clip10)
            video1 = title1.title
            video2 = title2.title
            video3 = title3.title
            video4 = title4.title
            video5 = title5.title
            video6 = title6.title
            video7 = title7.title
            video8 = title8.title
            video9 = title9.title
            video10 = title10.title
            Label(root,text=video1,fg='blue').place(x=60,y=70)
            print()
            print('1)', video1)
            print('2)', video2)
            print('3)', video3)
            print('4)', video4)
            print('5)', video5)
            print('6)', video6)
            print('7)', video7)
            print('8)', video8)
            print('9)', video9)
            print('10)', video10)
            print()
            e = input('Enter Song: ')
            if e == '1':
                print(clip1)
                url = clip1
            if e == '2':
                print(clip2)
                url = clip2
            if e == '3':
                print(clip2)
                url = clip3
            if e == '4':
                print(clip4)
                url = clip4
            if e == '5':
                print(clip5)
                url = clip5
            if e == '6':
                print(clip6)
                url = clip6
            if e == '7':
                print(clip7)
                url = clip7
            if e == '8':
                print(clip8)
                url = clip8
            if e == '9':
                print(clip9)
                url = clip9
            if e == '10':
                print(clip10)
                url = clip10
            video = pafy.new(url)
            best = video.getbest()
            media = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
            titl = video.title
            print(titl)
            media.play()
    def play():
        media.play()
    def pause():
        media.pause()
    def stop():
        media.stop()
    Search_button = Button(root, text = 'Search',  width = 10, font = ('Circular.', 10),bg='#1DB954',command=MusicPlayer.search)
    Play = Button(root, text = 'Play',  width = 10,font = ('Circular.', 10),bg='#1DB954',command=play)
    Pause = Button(root,text = 'Pause',  width = 10, font = ('Circular.', 10),bg='#1DB954',command=pause)
    Stop = Button(root,text = 'Stop',  width = 10, font = ('Circular.',10),bg='#1DB954',command=stop)
    Search_button.place(x=380,y=15);Play.place(x=120,y=170);Pause.place(x=220,y=170);Stop.place(x=320,y=170)
    root.mainloop()
```

This code works pretty well enough till the place where pausing/playing/stopping buttons.
Whenever I Try to press those button I get a ValueError: name 'media' is not defined.
[this is the link of the image of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80M9R.png).The Problem I think is because I'm trying to use something which is not under its indent(media).

[This is the player when it is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2QV7.png)

I also tried other ways of returning this media attribute but they don't seem to work for me. So, It would be good if someone could help me with this error and fix it.Also,I'm welcome to any suggestions you have for the program.

*Thanks*

*Sreeram*

Comment: First of all, your code doesn't follow PEP 8. Second of all, `media` is only defined inside your `search` function as it's not a global variable. Try adding `global media` to the start of your `search` function.

Comment: You get ```NameError``` for undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

In the function, make `media` global variable. However using `global` is bad. You can go with OOP approach where you can access the instance variable anywhere inside the function provided it is defined

```
global media
media = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
```

Comment: maaaaaan...It worked.!!!!! idk why i didnt think of that....adding global media makes it a global variable so we can access it anywhere ryt?..AWESOME.! btw Thanks Man

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that will work or not but try to pass the media value in the def
like:

```
def play(media):
   media.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `media` outside `search()` and use `media.set_mrl()` inside `search()` instead:

```py
media = vlc.MediaPlayer()

def search():
    ...
    best = video.getbest()
    media.set_mrl(best.url)
    ...
```